# Is it possible to set-up VR in the HDRP?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, virtual-reality

I'm trying to get VR to work in the HDRP.

I've tried VRTK and SteamVR, but found out that VRTK doesn't support the new SRPs yet. I'm wondering if there are any other methods I can try to get VR to work in the HDRP?